# Postgresql 8.3 doesn't understand negative interval greater than a day

Tags: postgresql, intervals, postgresql-8.3

The following statements are understood by Postgresql 8.3:

```
SELECT '1.12:00:00'::interval
SELECT '12:00:00'::interval
SELECT '-12:00:00'::interval
```

But the following statement isn't understood:

```
SELECT '-1.12:00:00'::interval
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "-1.00:02:00"

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "-1.00:02:00"
SQL state: 22007
```

How can I work with larger negative intervals?

Comment: Why do you think an interval can accept a dot to separate date and time in its [input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)?

Comment: Wow, it seems `interval '1.12:00:00'` is parsed as `interval '1 day 02:52:48'`, so you should read that as *1.12 days* (which is odd, but you shouldn't rely on this).

Comment: Version 8.3 is EOL since February 2013. Do yourself a favor and upgrade to a recent version: 8.3 has several serious (security) bugs. CVE-2013-1899 is probably the worst.

Comment: The upgrade issue is a whole other thing which might happen next summer or won't ever happen due to a migration to Sql Database (Azure).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The dot-notation was given to me by my simple c#-app that converts a .net-timespan to a postgres-interval. I haven't yet tested my routine on intervals more than a day, but I'll do so tomorrow.

Comment: It occurs to me that the .net TimeSpan works another way than Postgres considering intervals more than 24 hours. I'll try to make a decent INTERVAL out of the TimeSpan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation [for intervals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-datetime.html), I think the correct notation would be:

```
SELECT '-1 -12:00:00'::interval;  -- Assuming you want an interval equivalent to -36 hours

postgres=# select '-36 hours'::interval = '-1 -12:00:00'::interval;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Incidentally, it's possible that your notation of `1.12:00:00` isn't doing what it's intended - my interpretation is that you're trying to represent 36 hours (1 day + 12 hours) - due to the same notation issue.

```
postgres=# select
postgres-#   '1.12:00:00'::interval = '36 hours'::interval,
postgres-#   '1 12:00:00'::interval = '36 hours'::interval;
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 f        | t
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on reactions to my question and my own investigation, the problem turned out to be a mix of usage of two types: .NET's TimeSpan and NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlInterval. I have changed everything to NpgsqlInterval which solved my problem.

I can now work with larger negative values for intervals because of omitting the usage of the TimeSpan type. When the interval becomes larger than a day (negative), TimeSpan and Interval work differently so mixing these types isn't a good idea in this case.